# How to access parent of `classpath:` in JDBC url?

Tags: java, mysql, spring, jdbc

When running test, I use h2 database and there is a init.sql locating at `src/main/test/db/init.sql`.

If I use JDBC url like this:`spring.datasource.druid.url=jdbc:h2:mem:s;MODE=MYSQL;INIT=RUNSCRIPT FROM 'classpath:/db/init.sql'`, the program will look for it at 
`src/main/test/db/resources/db/init.sql`, which is not what the init.sql locate.

If I specify like this :`spring.datasource.druid.url=jdbc:h2:mem:s;MODE=MYSQL;INIT=RUNSCRIPT FROM 'classpath:/../db/init.sql'`, it will display some error saying it cannot find the file.

The question is that, what url should I specify to make JDBC look for the init.sql in `src/main/test/db/init.sql`?

Comment: Have you given try to this: `spring.datasource.druid.url=jdbc:h2:mem:s;MODE=MYSQL;INIT=RUNSCRIPT FROM 'classpath:src/main/test/db/init.sql'`

Answer (score 1):

When running your test, the `init.sql` file is searched for in the resources folder because   [by default for maven projects](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-standard-directory-layout.html) when running a test, the `/src/test/resources` directory contents are placed in the root of your `CLASSPATH`. So when you specify the classpath as an environment variable in the `spring.datasource.druid.url` property as in your question, the `/src/test/resources/` directory is prepended.

**To answer you question, to ensure the `init.sql` file can be found using your specified property `spring.datasource.druid.url=jdbc:h2:mem:s;MODE=MYSQL;INIT=RUNSCRIPT FROM 'classpath:/db/init.sql'`, you need to change the default maven resources folder by modifying the `pom.xml` build tag as following:**

```
<build>
    <resources>
        <resource>
            <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
        </resource>
        <resource>
            <directory>src/test</directory>
        </resource>
    </resources>
</build>
```

I would suggest for best practice, you rather move your `init.sql` file to the `src/test/resources` folder and use the property `spring.datasource.druid.url=jdbc:h2:mem:s;MODE=MYSQL;INIT=RUNSCRIPT FROM 'classpath:init.sql'` which should work.